# How do I solve $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = e^ {9y-x}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = e^ {9y-x}$

I substituted $v = 9y-x$ (homogeneous).

And I tried separable integration, but why do I get the wrong answers? We can separate it, can't we?

Comment: $\displaystyle \int e^{-9y}~dy = \int e^{-x}~dx$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:  We can separate $e^{9y-x}$ as $\dfrac{e^{9y}}{e^x}$. Then our equation transforms to $$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{e^{9y}} = \dfrac{\mathrm dx}{e^x}$$ which can be easily solved (i.e., by integration). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=e^{9y-x}$

$\implies e^{-9y}\,\mathrm dy=e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx$

$\implies \displaystyle \int e^{-9y}\,\mathrm d
y=\int e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx$

$\implies -\dfrac{1}{9}e^{-9y}=-e^{-x}+C$

$\implies e^{-9y}=9e^{-x}-9C$

$\implies  y=-\dfrac{1}{9}\ln|9e^{-x}-9C|$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 9y - x$

Put v = 9y - x

Then differentiate w.r.t x,

$\frac{dv}{dx} = 9 \frac{dy}{dx} - 1$

$\frac{\frac{dv}{dx} +1}{9} = \frac{dy}{dx}$

On replacing values of v and $\frac{dy}{dx}$

$\frac{\frac{dv}{dx} +1}{9} = v$

$\frac{dv}{dx} = 9v - 1$

$\frac{dv}{9v - 1} = dx$

On integrating both sides,

$\frac{log|9v - 1|}{9} = x + c$

$\frac{log|9(9y-x) - 1|}{9} = x + c$